# Possible to play back table of inserts/deletes to get the current state?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have a table which stores equipment as a history of changes, e.g.:

Sample table PartHistory (also includes a numerical primary key):

```
ID  Hst Data    Set Date    (desired result)
1   I   partA   1   2014-07-01  
2   I   partB   1   2014-07-01  
3   I   partC   1   2014-07-01  Parts A, B, C
4   D   partC   2   2014-07-03  Parts A, B
5   I   partZ   3   2014-07-06  Parts A, B, Z
6   D   partA   4   2014-07-20  
7   D   partZ   4   2014-07-20  
8   I   partC   4   2014-07-20  
9   I   partQ   4   2014-07-20  Parts B, C, Q
```

Each set involves one or more I - Inserts (new equipment) D - Deletes (equipment removal). Valid data (no removal of non existent equipment, etc.) can be assumed.

Is it possible to use standard SQL (not PL/SQL) to query this data such that I can get the state of equipment on a specific date or set?

For example:

```
SELECT data, set, date FROM (...ninja SQL...) WHERE ChangeDate = DATE '2014-07-03'

partA   2   2014-07-03
partB   2   2014-07-03


SELECT data, set, date FROM (...ninja SQL...) WHERE set = 4

partB   4   2014-07-20
partC   4   2014-07-20
partQ   4   2014-07-20
```

Comment: What does the second column represent in the first set of results?

Comment: Hst - Inserts / Deletes - its below the first snippet of code.

Comment: @Gordon: The second result column is the "set" column. I've edited the SQL to make this more clear.

Comment: The "set" column for A and B is "1" on the rows.  How does it magically become 2?

Comment: @GordonLinoff: Each set value represents a group if inserts or deletes, so on row 4 where the set value changes to 2, that's a different set of changes than rows 1-3 which were insertions for A, B, and C

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the parts and the most recent counts "as-of" a particular date, you can do this in SQL with this structure.  Basically, add up the number of "I" values and subtract the number of "D" values to get the count.

```
select data, sum(case when hst = 'I' then 1 when hst = 'D' then -1 else 0 end) as num
from parthistory ph
where ChangeDate <= DATE '2014-07-03'
group by data
having sum(case when hst = 'I' then 1 when hst = 'D' then -1 else 0 end) > 0;
```

Comment: +1: Fast, beautiful, and I can even use this to test validity of current equipment data (stored in a separate table).